# bootstrap datepicker not retaining value on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working on bootstrap datepicker.

```
function initializeDatePicker() {
    $('#milestone_start_date').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        startDate: '-1m',
        endDate: '+13m',
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#milestone_end_date').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    });

    $('#milestone_end_date').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#milestone_start_date').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
    });
}
```

I called this function for multiple times to update input startDate, EndDate fields.

```
$('#milestone_end_date').datepicker('destroy');
$('#milestone_start_date').datepicker('destroy');

$('#milestone_start_date').val(data.start_date);
$('#milestone_end_date').val(data.end_date);

initializeDatePicker();
```

After AJAX call, correct values are displayed in start, `EndDate` popups. But if I clicked `startDate` field. And `focusOut` from the field. Value in `startDate` changes to today.

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am calling multiple times initializeDatePicker(); function to re-initialize.